# How to render images in React JS

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am new to coding so please bear with me -
I am trying to create a dynamic gallery display, in which all the images will be taken from the database and should render in the overall layout as below.
[Expected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7wb8.jpg)

I am unable to make it render in this manner instead it shows second image on repeat for 3rd image position.
[Current Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/haEuU.jpg)

Attaching the code below which I currently have, any feedback/suggestion would be of great help to me. Thanks in advance.

Data:-

```
const GALLERY = [
    {
       qty:1, img_path:`${AMAZON_URL}/Gallery/1.jpg`,
    },
    {
        qty:2, img_path:`${AMAZON_URL}/Gallery/2.jpg`,
    },
    {
        qty:2, img_path:`${AMAZON_URL}/Gallery/3.jpg`,
    },
    {
        qty:1, img_path:`${AMAZON_URL}/Gallery/4.jpg`,
    },
    {
        qty:2, img_path:`${AMAZON_URL}/Gallery/5.jpg`,
    },
    {
        qty:2, img_path:`${AMAZON_URL}/Gallery/6.jpg`,
    },
]



{GALLERY.map((item, index) => (
                                <>
                                {item.qty === 1?
                                    <Grid item xs="6" my="2" key={index}>
                                        <img className="W100" src={item.img_path}  /> 
                                    </Grid>
                                    :
                                    <Grid item xs="6" my="2" key={index}>
                                        <img className="W100" src={item.img_path}  />
                                        <img className="W100" src={item.img_path}  />
                                    </Grid>
                                }                              
                                </>
                             ))}
```

Comment: what all CSS you added?

Comment: The "else" condition of the ternary renders 2 of the same image instead of just one into a single grid area.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on image sizes you would have more success ditching the col and having the images modified inside the Grid with CSS. If the images are appropriately sized something like this could work.

```
   <Grid>
   {GALLERY.map((item, index) => (
       <img className="W100" src={item.img_path}  /> 
   ))} 
   </Grid>

   img {
       width:50%;
       float:left;
   }
```

Comment: as per your suggestion, I tried but not fix my layout it goes to all image as a square